# Tweepy error with bookmarks, TypeError: unhashable type: 'OAuth2Token'

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, tweepy

I'm trying to write a script to delete bookmarks, and I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/authentication.html) up to the tweepy client step and I'm trying to then go from [here](https://improveandrepeat.com/2022/07/python-friday-131-working-with-bookmarks-in-tweepy/) for bookmark manipulation.

Here's my code, and I only get an error once line 25 is reached:

```
import tweepy

oauth2_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth2UserHandler(
    client_id="id",
    redirect_uri="https://127.0.0.1",
    scope=["bookmark.read", "bookmark.write",
        "tweet.read","users.read"],
 
    client_secret="secret"
)

print(oauth2_user_handler.get_authorization_url())


verifier = input("Enter whole callback URL: ")

 
access_token = oauth2_user_handler.fetch_token(verifier)


client = tweepy.Client(access_token)



response = client.get_bookmarks(expansions="author_id,attachments.media_keys",
    tweet_fields="created_at,public_metrics,attachments",
    user_fields="username,name,profile_image_url",
    media_fields="public_metrics,url,height,width,alt_text")
```

What should I do about the unhasheable type error? EDIT: added full error traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RosenKids\Desktop\Manim projects\tweepyBookmarkTesting.py", line 25, in <module>
    client.get_bookmarks(expansions="author_id,attachments.media_keys", #I need the access token! <-- learned this from reading the documentation for type error!
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 363, in get_bookmarks
    id = self._get_authenticating_user_id()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 245, in _get_authenticating_user_id
    return self._get_oauth_2_authenticating_user_id(
TypeError: unhashable type: 'OAuth2Token'
```

I did a bit more research and it says that get_bookmarks will return a TypeError when the access token isn't set. But haven't I already done that?
I ran a test to see what the attribute access_token is set to with a print, and it returned None, which means the documentation for PKCE 2.0 flow isn't setting the access token I think. Weird

Comment: Show us the **full** error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. done, I added it to the bottom of my post

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it.

I noticed in the documentation that the access key is supposed to be a string.
I got that string of an access key by doing:

```
accessToken = oauth2_user_handler.fetch_token(verifier)


print("The returned access token is ", accessToken)


accessCopy = input("Copy paste the access token here \n >") 

client = tweepy.Client(accessCopy)
```

While this statement still returns none, meaning the access_token attribute is none, the bookmark function worked A OK:

```
print("The client access token is ", client.access_token)
```

So that's cool